# Object type to columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm familiar with Oracle's objects, nested tables, table() functions etc.
But is it possible to create object type where you have e.g. two varchar2 columns and select that type as columns without creating nested table type of that object type?

I have tried to create type and function which is returning that. And selecting that function result, but the result is showing object type (not columns like I would like it). With table type it would be easy to use table() which casts object types fields to regular columns.

I would need it like this:

```
SELECT MY_FUNC(params)
FROM   DUAL
```

And result would be:

```
|field 1| |field 2|
 txt1      txt2
```

But the result is now:

```
|MY_FUNC(params)|
(txt1; txt2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to treat an object directly as a table, without declaring the nested table type based on the object.  However, if what you're trying to avoid is modifying the function, you can do that by casting the function result in your SQL statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE testtype AS OBJECT( x NUMBER, y NUMBER);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE testtypetab AS TABLE OF testtype;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testfunc RETURN testtype AS
BEGIN
  RETURN testtype(1,1);
END testfunc;
/

select * from table(cast(multiset(select testfunc from dual) as testtypetab));
```

Comment: Ok, so it's impossible and just what I thought.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Oracle objects to return more than one piece of data. Consider:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t AS OBJECT (
  2     x NUMBER,
  3     y NUMBER
  4  );
  5  /

Type created

SQL> SELECT a.obj.x, a.obj.y FROM (SELECT t(0,1) obj FROM DUAL) a;

     OBJ.X      OBJ.Y
---------- ----------
         0          1
```

Comment: Thanks! But also with this I have to define what columns I want to retrieve.

Comment: @Jokke: yes, SQL is a declarative language, you need to know beforehand the name of columns/objects.

Comment: No if you are using nested tables with table() function you don't have to. Just use asterisk. But that was not what I wanted so...

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do this with a [pipelined table function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#sthref2345), so it would look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg
AS

    TYPE rec_t IS RECORD(field_1 varchar2(10), field_2 varchar2(10));

    TYPE tbl_t IS TABLE OF rec_t;

    FUNCTION my_func(p1_in IN NUMBER)
    RETURN tbl_t
    PIPELINED;

END test_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg
AS

    FUNCTION my_func(p1_in IN NUMBER)
    RETURN tbl_t
    PIPELINED
    IS
        rec REC_T;
    BEGIN    
        IF p1_in > 10
        THEN
            rec.field_1 := 'one';
            rec.field_2 := 'two';
        ELSE
            rec.field_1 := 'three';
            rec.field_2 := 'four';
        END IF;

        PIPE ROW(rec);      

        RETURN;

    END my_func;

END test_pkg;
```

Which could then be queried as:

```
select *
from table(test_pkg.my_func(2))
```

Which returns:

```
FIELD_1 FIELD_2
three     four
```

Comment: Yes of course, but with this you need a nested table type. So no help.

Comment: Why are you opposed to creating the nested table type?

Comment: Maybe I have to use nested table type, but the idea was to only retrieve one row when function was executed. Normally I have used functions in SQL to retrieve one value but now I wanted to retrieve multiple values (columns) with single execution (object type). But it seems that it's not possible to get object type values as columns in SQL without pointing each field separately...

Comment: Keep in mind that nothing says you have to return more than one row from the table function.  You don't even have to ever use the nested table, it is just used to define the type of output.

Comment: I have updated the above post with a quick example of the table function that will return just the one row.

Comment: Craig, actually I didn't knew that you can use pipelined function in SQL with types declared inside of package. Normally I have created schema types, but this rocks! Thx!

Comment: @JokkeHeikkilä: What really happens here is that the PL/SQL compiler will generate synthetic SQL types. There's probably a bridge between the pipelined function and the actual function being called from SQL...